# streamlit Authenticate.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'cookie_expiry_days'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, streamlit

I'm building a basic streamlit app. In order to validate user credentials, I'm using the [authentification](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-authenticator/0.1.3/) module of [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/). Only one problem, the code does not work !

#### ERROR

> TypeError: Authenticate.**init**() got multiple values for argument 'cookie_expiry_days'
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Users_M92\Desktop\Coding\Python\Projects\Personal1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script exec(code, module.**dict**)
>
> File "app.py", line 23, in 
> authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(names, usernames, hashed_passwords,

By the way, I used the same code described [here](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-authenticator/0.1.3/) in the official documentation :

#### CODE

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit_authenticator as stauth

names = ['John Smith', 'Rebecca Briggs']
usernames = ['jsmith', 'rbriggs']
passwords = ['123', '456']

hashed_passwords = stauth.Hasher(passwords).generate()

authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(names, usernames, hashed_passwords,
    'some_cookie_name', 'some_signature_key', cookie_expiry_days=30)

name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login('Login', 'main')

if authentication_status:
    authenticator.logout('Logout', 'main')
    st.write('Welcome *%s*' % (name))
    st.title('Some content')
elif authentication_status == False:
    st.error('Username/password is incorrect')
elif authentication_status == None:
    st.warning('Please enter your username and password')

if st.session_state['authentication_status']:
    st.write('Welcome *%s*' % (st.session_state['name']))
    st.title('Some content')
elif st.session_state['authentication_status'] == False:
    st.error('Username/password is incorrect')
elif st.session_state['authentication_status'] == None:
    st.warning('Please enter your username and password')
```

When I removed the argument `cookie_expiry_days=30`, I get this error instead :

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>
> File"C:\Users_M92\Desktop\Coding\Python\Projects\Personal1\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit_authenticator\authenticate.py",line
> 36, in __init__self.credentials['usernames'] = {key.lower(): value for
> key, value in credentials['usernames'].items()}

Do you have any idea why I keep getting these errors ?

Comment: There is now a new version `streamlit-authenticator 0.2.1`.

Comment: Thank you so much @ferdy. You helped me solve the problem. Actually, I was using a code of the 0.1.3 version while I have installed the 0.2.1 version. Now, I changed the code and it worked. I will add an answer later on to explain exactly what I did. Thank you man !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So since 2 days later and still no reply from OP :p here's what I found after checking out 0.2.1 as ferdy pointed out...

the new format requires a credentials dictionary, the [example](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-authenticator/) given is like this

```
credentials:   
 usernames:
    jsmith:
      email: jsmith@gmail.com
      name: John Smith
      password: '123' # To be replaced with hashed password
    rbriggs:
      email: rbriggs@gmail.com
      name: Rebecca Briggs
      password: '456' # To be replaced with hashed password 
 cookie:   expiry_days: 30   
 key: some_signature_key   
 name: some_cookie_name 
 preauthorized:   emails:
   - melsby@gmail.com
```

but since that wants a yaml and I basically had it all set up the old way (based on Coding is Fun's [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCbH2nPL9sU&t=3s&ab_channel=CodingIsFun) tutorial), i wanted to just pass the credentials to the authenticator directly, so if your original code is like this...

```
authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(names, usernames, passwords, "app_home", "auth", cookie_expiry_days=30)
```

what you want is a dictionary like this

```
    credentials = {
        "usernames":{
            usernames[0]:{
                "name":names[0],
                "password":passwords[0]
                },
            usernames[1]:{
                "name":names[1],
                "password":passwords[1]
                }            
            }
        }
```

Then you pass that to authenticator like so...

```
authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(credentials, "app_home", "auth", cookie_expiry_days=30)
```

so just to clarify your resulting credentials dictionary will look something like this...

```
    credentials = {
        "usernames":{
            "jsmith92":{
                "name":"john smith",
                "password":"$2b$12$TSuKwWML0EpbohBQgHx4p8E5q"
                },
            "tturner":{
                "name":"timmy turner",
                "password":"$2b$12$asdaUduuibuEIyBUBHASD896a"
                }            
            }
        }
```

As you may note I've not included the cookie part in the dictionary (as they state you should in the config.yaml) and it still works just fine

Now of course you can fill in these variables in a loop based on how many items you have in each list (names, passwords, usernames) but if you just want to quickly test one or two sets of credentials this is a quick and easy way to do so.

For reference here is the loop that i used to create the final credentials dictionary dynamically based on any number of credentials in the users, names, and passwords lists...

```
credentials = {"usernames":{}}

for un, name, pw in zip(usernames, names, passwords):
    user_dict = {"name":name,"password":pw}
    credentials["usernames"].update({un:user_dict})

authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(credentials, "app_home", "auth", cookie_expiry_days=30)
```

First initialise the credentials dictionary with the usernames key and an empty dictionary as the value.

Then zip the credentials (usernames, names, password) together and loop them. Note for my example - un means username, pw means password

Then we add each user_dict to the credentials dictionary as a value under the "usernames" key by using the update function. Note - be sure to wrap the dictionary in {} in the update part i.e. .update({un:user_dict})

You may also want to add a logout button once the user has verified since the login form disappears once the user is authenticated (30 day cookies) making it practically impossible to test if you don't have one.

You can do that with a simple if statement, using the authentication_status from earlier like so...

```
if authentication_status == True:
    authenticator.logout("logout","main")
```

Sorry its long but figured id update to include the actual loop i used, here is the code I used which is working, in it's entirety for anyone who wants it

```
    # my class function which makes a call to a database and returns a list of lists (nested list), of usernames, names, and passwords
    users = usr.get_all_users_credentials()
    # the code mentioned above
    usernames = [user[1] for user in users]
    names = [user[2] for user in users]
    passwords = [user[3] for user in users]

    credentials = {"usernames":{}}

    for un, name, pw in zip(usernames, names, passwords):
        user_dict = {"name":name,"password":pw}
        credentials["usernames"].update({un:user_dict})

    authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(credentials, "app_home", "auth", cookie_expiry_days=30)

    name, authentication_status, username = authenticator.login("Login", "main")

    if authentication_status == True:
        authenticator.logout("logout","main")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
hashed_passwords = stauth.hasher(passwords).generate() # Changed .Hasher to .hasher

authenticator = stauth.authenticate(names, usernames, hashed_passwords,
    'some_cookie_name', 'some_signature_key', cookie_expiry_days=30) # Changed .Authenticate to .authenticate
```

Your code should be up and running now.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Streamlit_authenticator requires the credentials in a dictionary form, that's why we got the error, the following code will help.

```
usernames = ['user1','user2']
names = ['name1','name2']
passwords = ['pwd1','pwd2']

credentials = {"usernames":{}}
        
for uname,name,pwd in zip(usernames,names,passwords):
    user_dict = {"name": name, "password": pwd}
    credentials["usernames"].update({uname: user_dict})
        
authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(credentials, "cokkie_name", "random_key", cookie_expiry_days=30)


# output==>
{'usernames': {'user1': {'name': 'name1', 'password': 'pwd1'}, 'user2': {'name': 'name2', 'password': 'pwd2'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pip install streamlit-authenticator==0.1.5
```

ref:
https://github.com/Sven-Bo/streamlit-sales-dashboard-with-userauthentication/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

With streamlit authenticator you must use it with the Hasher method in order to get your authentication to work. It is not necessary to save a yaml file especially if your app is connecting to a database.

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit_authenticator as stauth 

credentials = {"usernames":{}}
db = db()
users = []
passwords = []
names = []

for row in db.fetch_all_users():
    users.append(row["key"])
    names.append(row["name"])
    passwords.append(row["password"])
    
hashed_passwords = stauth.Hasher(passwords).generate()
for un, name, pw in zip(users, names, hashed_passwords):   
    user_dict = {"name":name,"password":pw}
    credentials["usernames"].update({un:user_dict})
```